# Converter um codígo em jquery para Javascript puro

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Tenho um código jquery que gostaria de converte-lo para javascript puro, DOM. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
var mobileItems = jQuery( '#slide-out .nav-mobile .main-menu' );
mobileItems.find( 'li.menu-item-has-children' ).append( '<i class="mobile-arrows fa fa-chevron-down"></i>' );
jQuery("li.menu-item-has-children i.mobile-arrows").click(function() {
    if( jQuery( this ).hasClass( "fa-chevron-down" ) )
        jQuery( this ).removeClass( "fa-chevron-down" ).addClass( "fa-chevron-up" );
    else
        jQuery( this ).removeClass( "fa-chevron-up" ).addClass( "fa-chevron-down" );

    jQuery( this ).parent().find('ul:first').toggle();
});

var mobileItems = jQuery( '#slide-out .st-nav-mobile .main-menu' );
mobileItems.find( 'div.penci-mega-latest-posts' ).remove();
mobileItems.find( 'div.mega-cat-content-tab' ).remove();
mobileItems.find( 'div.mega-recent-post' ).remove();
mobileItems.find('.mega-cat-wrapper').unwrap();
mobileItems.find('.mega-cat-sub-categories').unwrap();
```

Comment: Sem o html fica difícil. Tente dessa forma: https://pastebin.com/wwDfY2TP

Comment: Não precisa botar a solução na pergunta. Se a resposta ajudou, basta votar positivamente e aceitá-la, como ja fez. Caso sua solução seja diferente da pergunta, você pode responder a pergunta com a que você encontrou.

Comment: De boa. Vlw pela dica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Criei um HTML que reproduz a estrutura dos elementos dos seletores no jQuery para que possa ver o funcionamento. O código foi testado tanto com jQuery e no JS puro abaixo e obteve o mesmo efeito. Vou deixar comentários no código para que se possa saber o que ele faz (no final da resposta vou deixar o código *limpo*):

```js
// Busco todos os elementos-filhos do seletor. Similar ao .find usado no jQuery
var mobileItems = document.querySelectorAll('#slide-out .nav-mobile .main-menu li.menu-item-has-children');
[].forEach.call(mobileItems, function(el){
   var i = document.createElement('i');
   i.setAttribute('class','mobile-arrows fa fa-chevron-down');
   
   // aqui eu coloquei um texto apenas como exemplo para ser clicado
   // estas duas linhas pode apagar
   var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
   i.appendChild(t);
   // apagar as duas linhas acima
   
   el.appendChild(i);
});

// Aqui eu percorro os elementos <i> e adiciono um event handler
// similar ao jQuery("li.menu-item-has-children i.mobile-arrows").click(function() {
var li_i = document.querySelectorAll('li.menu-item-has-children i.mobile-arrows');
[].forEach.call(li_i, function(el){
   el.addEventListener('click', function(){
      if(this.className.indexOf('fa-chevron-down') != -1){
         this.classList.remove("fa-chevron-down");
         this.classList.add("fa-chevron-up");
      }else{
         this.classList.remove("fa-chevron-up");
         this.classList.add("fa-chevron-down");
      }
      
      // Aqui eu altero a visibilidade do primeiro <ul> 
      // similar ao jQuery( this ).parent().find('ul:first').toggle();
      var ul = this.parentNode.querySelectorAll('ul')[0];
      ul.style.display = ul.offsetParent === null ? 'block' : 'none';

   });
});

// Aqui eu faço o desembrulho dos elementos indicados no jQuery
var mobileItems = document.querySelectorAll('#slide-out .st-nav-mobile .main-menu *');
var elpai = mobileItems[0].parentNode;
[].forEach.call(mobileItems, function(el){

   // unwrap (desembrulhar). Ao desembrulhar um elemento, todos os irmãos também são,
   // porque o elemento-pai é removido
   elpai.parentNode.appendChild(el);

   var tn = el.nodeName.toLowerCase();
   if(tn == "div" && el.className.indexOf('penci-mega-latest-posts') != -1) el.outerHTML = '';
   if(tn == "div" && el.className.indexOf('mega-cat-content-tab') != -1) el.outerHTML = '';
   if(tn == "div" && el.className.indexOf('mega-recent-post') != -1) el.outerHTML = '';
   
});

// Removendo elemento-pai do for acima
elpai.outerHTML = '';
```

```html
<div id="slide-out">
   <div class="nav-mobile">
      <div class="main-menu">
         <ul>
            <li class="menu-item-has-children">
               <ul>
                  ul1
               </ul>
               <ul>
                  ul2
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item-has-children">
               <ul>
                  ul1
               </ul>
               <ul>
                  ul2
               </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="st-nav-mobile">
      <div class="main-menu">
         <div class="penci-mega-latest-posts">
            penci-mega-latest-posts1
         </div>
         <div class="penci-mega-latest-posts">
            penci-mega-latest-posts2
         </div>
         <div class="mega-cat-content-tab">
            mega-cat-content-tab1
         </div>
         <div class="mega-cat-content-tab">
            mega-cat-content-tab2
         </div>
         <div class="mega-recent-post">
            mega-recent-post1
         </div>
         <div class="mega-recent-post">
            mega-recent-post2
         </div>
         <div class="mega-cat-wrapper">
            mega-cat-wrapper1
         </div>
         <div class="mega-cat-wrapper">
            mega-cat-wrapper2
         </div>
         <div class="mega-cat-sub-categories">
            mega-cat-sub-categories1
         </div>
         <div class="mega-cat-sub-categories">
            mega-cat-sub-categories2
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

#### Código limpo:

```
var mobileItems = document.querySelectorAll('#slide-out .nav-mobile .main-menu li.menu-item-has-children');
[].forEach.call(mobileItems, function(el){
   var i = document.createElement('i');
   i.setAttribute('class','mobile-arrows fa fa-chevron-down');
   el.appendChild(i);
});

var li_i = document.querySelectorAll('li.menu-item-has-children i.mobile-arrows');
[].forEach.call(li_i, function(el){
   el.addEventListener('click', function(){
      if(this.className.indexOf('fa-chevron-down') != -1){
         this.classList.remove("fa-chevron-down");
         this.classList.add("fa-chevron-up");
      }else{
         this.classList.remove("fa-chevron-up");
         this.classList.add("fa-chevron-down");
      }
      
      var ul = this.parentNode.querySelectorAll('ul')[0];
      ul.style.display = ul.offsetParent === null ? 'block' : 'none';

   });
});

var mobileItems = document.querySelectorAll('#slide-out .st-nav-mobile .main-menu *');
var elpai = mobileItems[0].parentNode;
[].forEach.call(mobileItems, function(el){
   elpai.parentNode.appendChild(el);

   var tn = el.nodeName.toLowerCase();
   if(tn == "div" && el.className.indexOf('penci-mega-latest-posts') != -1) el.outerHTML = '';
   if(tn == "div" && el.className.indexOf('mega-cat-content-tab') != -1) el.outerHTML = '';
   if(tn == "div" && el.className.indexOf('mega-recent-post') != -1) el.outerHTML = '';
});

elpai.outerHTML = '';
```

> **Compatibilidade:** IE10+, Chrome, Firefox, Opera (estes mais recentes) e até Safari 5 do Windows que foi abandonado há muito tempo.

Comment: Simplesmente maravilhoso. Com o seu código fiz um exemplo completo no codepen. https://codepen.io/johnquimera/pen/EorBjO

Obrigado.

Comment: @JohnQuimera Valeu brother! Boa sorte!

Comment: de boa, eu é que agradeço.

Comment: permita-me tomar um pouco mais de seu tempo. No codigo jquery eu utilizava slideToggle(300) e  toggleClass('is-open') com transform: rotate(180deg); na classe "is-open" para criar um efeito bonitinho. https://pastebin.com/b5XxZJd0 é possível fazer isso também nesse código?

Comment: de boa, publiquei no codepen o mesmo menu em jquery com o efeito. https://codepen.io/johnquimera/pen/qpgedN

Comment: @JohnQuimera Dá uma olhada https://jsfiddle.net/rtw0vjdw/

Comment: muito bom, muito bom mesmo, eu apliquei o seu codigo no meu exemplo no codpen. Ficou ótimo, o negócio é que o sub-menu ele já nasce aberto. veja: https://codepen.io/johnquimera/pen/MrxWyG

Comment: Muda essa linha: `ul.style.height = ul.offsetHeight+'px';` pra isso `ul.style.height = '0';` e coloca esta linha `ul.setAttribute('data-h',ul.offsetHeight);` antes da linha acima.

Comment: Cara, isso é arte. Está perfeito!! Mil agradecimentos. https://codepen.io/johnquimera/pen/MrxWyG

Comment: Alterei o exemplo no code pen, estava testando o sub-menu dentro de outro sub-menu. Mas o height do primeiro sub-menu não permite expandir o sub-menu dentro dele. veja "Sub Menu in Sub Menu" https://codepen.io/johnquimera/pen/MrxWyG

Comment: @JohnQuimera Arrumei: https://jsfiddle.net/rtw0vjdw/2/  ... só tem um probleminha na seta dos submenus que não estão fechando quando fecha o menu-pai mas isso eu resolvo aqui rapidinho..

Comment: @JohnQuimera Resolvido o lance da seta: https://jsfiddle.net/rtw0vjdw/3/

Comment: Opa, perfeito, valeu, gostei do jsfiddle, criei uma conta, fiz um fork. Eu sou um psicopata, coloquei outro submenu dentro do sub menu no submenu. O erro do height persiste nele. Não que seja grande coisa, um sub menu dentro de outro submenu já é exagerado, mesmo assim... acho que eu poderia replicar o código da sua solução nesse mesmo problema, mas acho que não seria o ideal, já que teria que fazer o mesmo até o infinito não? https://jsfiddle.net/johnquimera/v54qyqtg/5/

Comment: poderia me ajudar em outra pergunta sobre javascript? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/271143/remover-class-e-alterar-valor-aria-hidden-ao-clicar-no-body

Comment: @JohnQuimera Vou olhar... até tinha me esquecido da questão acima. Para mais de um submenu, teria que fazer uma contagem. Creio que isso não seja grande problema.