# Evitar que menu Dropdown feche com o Clique direito dentro dele

Tags: javascript, dom

Gostaria que esse menu Dropdown não fechasse ao clicar com o botão direito do mouse dentro dele para abrir um link em uma nova aba.

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
 /* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #3498DB;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #2980B9;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
```

```html
 <div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remova o código de `window.onclick`

Comment: Clique esquerdo ou direito?

Comment: @dvd é o direito, eu me confundi aqui, o que abre as opções do Browser, "Abrir em uma nova aba" etc...

Comment: Por favor, altera na pergunta senão a pergunta fica sem sentido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que vi, isso só acontece no **Firefox Quantum 57**, que captura um clique direito do mouse no evento `onclick`, embora não faça ação no elemento (como se fosse um clique esquerdo).

Para resolver isso, você pode adicionar outro *event handler* no submenu com `oncontextmenu`, que detecta o clique direito do mouse. Neste caso você pode adicionar a classe `.show` ao elemento. Isso fará que ele não se feche mesmo clicando com o botão direito.

Como dito no início, deve ser testado no FF Quantum 57. Nos demais navegadores não existe esse problema:

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
      document.querySelector(".dropdown-content").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}   

var drop = document.querySelector(".dropdown-content");
drop.oncontextmenu = function(event) {
   drop.classList.add("show");
}
```

```css
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #3498DB;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #2980B9;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfeito. É exatamente isso. Obrigado.

Comment: pretendo usar 2 ou até 3 desses dropdowns numa mesma página, eu tentei aqui, mas existe conflitos. Como eu devera prosseguir? Eu queria algo semelhante a esses menus dropdowns com icones do StackOverflow. É claro que tentei furta-los, mas sem sucesso.. rsrs

Comment: @JohnQuimera Veja que o menu tem um id="myDropdown"... se vc duplicar vai dar conflito porque o script não sabe diferenciar um id do outro, ele sempre vai pegar o primeiro que encontrar... teria que adaptar o código e trocando id por class.. quanto aos ícones, tem um plugin que já vem com vários ícones, acho que é o font-awesome

Comment: eu já troquei todos os document.getElementById() por document.querySelector() e agora só estou usando classes, está funcionando do mesmo jeito, mas não funciona dois na mesma página.

Comment: @JohnQuimera Tem que fazer querySelectorAll para selecionar todos e depois fazer um loop

Comment: tem um dropdown que é igual a esse, em jquery, suporta vários desses, só preciso fazer o mesmo esquema do click esquerdo e resolver o problema de fechar o outro dropdown quando outro for aberto. https://codepen.io/johnquimera/pen/RxzEQr

Comment: @JohnQuimera Posta perguntas que a gente tenta resolver.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/271977/dropdowns-multiplos-na-mesma-p%c3%a1gina

Comment: acho que isso é algo que você consegue resolver, me dê uma mãozinha. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/276470/jquery-dropdown-parar-propaga%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-click-direito?noredirect=1

Comment: Blz, to vendo aqui.