# Dropdowns multiplos na mesma página

Tags: jquery

Estou tendo um problema com o exemplo abaixo. Vários dropdowns em jquery numa mesma página, todos eles abrem perfeitamente, mas todos ficam abertos, mesmo quando clicado em outro dropdown, queria que apenas um dropdown ficasse aberto, e que quando clicado em outro, o mesmo fechasse. E também que ele não feche quando clicado com o botão direito dentro dele.

```js
$(document).on('click',".dropbtn",function(){
  $(this).next(".dropdown-content").toggle( "show" );
});
// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    $(".dropdown-content").hide(100);
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
  
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Botão direito" rsrs

Comment: @dvd editado... rsrsrs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O uso do `.hide()` causa conflito. Porque quando o elemento recebe um `.hide()`, a classe `.show` não fará efeito, porque ao usar `.hide()` o elemento recebe um *style* *inline* que tem mais força que uma classe no CSS.

O correto seria criar uma outra classe oposta ao `.show`, que nomeei `.hide`.

Coloquei 2 códigos: em JS puro (comentado) e em jQuery:

```js
$(document).on('click',".dropbtn",function(){
  $(".dropdown-content").not($(this).next(".dropdown-content")).removeClass("show");
  $(this).next(".dropdown-content").toggleClass("show");  
});
// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    $(".dropdown-content").removeClass("show");
  }
}

//var drop = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-content");
//for(var x=0; x<drop.length; x++){
//   drop[x].oncontextmenu = function(event) {
//      console.log(this.innerHTML);
//      this.classList.add("show");
//   }
//}

$(".dropdown-content").on("contextmenu", function(){
   $(this).addClass("show");
});
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}
.hide {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home1</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home2</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home3</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
  
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home4</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfeito como sempre, valeu!

Comment: editei seu exemplo ai, coloquei um form no dropdown, queria que o quando clicado no dropdown com tivesse um input, ele já estivesse com focus, e que o dropdown não feche quando clicar dentro do input. Eu tentei faze-lo com com "$('.search-input').focus();" dentro do evento click, funciona mais ou menos, o focus entra em ação apenas quando está fechando.

Answer (score 1):

Segue:

```js
$(document).on('click',".dropbtn",function(){
  $(".dropdown-content").hide(100);
  $(this).next(".dropdown-content").toggle();  
});
// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    $(".dropdown-content").hide(100);
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
  
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: isso, mas o dropdown aberto não fecha quando clicado nele mesmo... e tem ainda a questão do contextmenu, para que o toggle não tenha efeito quando clicado como botão direito no link dentro do dropdown.

Comment: Ahhh, agora eu entendi

Comment: Só a parte do botão direito que eu não saquei o que você espera e qual o motivo.

Comment: sabe esse menu dropdown de notificações do StackOverflow? Se você clica com o botão direito para abrir uma notificação em uma nova aba, ele não fecha, é desse estilo que eu queria.

Comment: Numa outra pergunta que fiz, sobre menu semelhante, só em em javascript puro, o camarada @dvd apresentou uma boa solução, mas como eu precisava usar vários dropdowns numa mesma pagina, eu fiz essa outra pergunta com esse dropdown em jquery. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/271898/evitar-que-menu-dropdown-feche-com-o-clique-direito-dentro-dele/271935?noredirect=1

Comment: @JohnQuimera mas esse é o comportamento apresentado, faça o teste, clique com o botão direito e mande abrir um subitem em uma nova guia, ou clique com o esquero fora da área de preview se você não quer que o submenu feche ao clicar fora dele, remova o evento `onclick` do `window`

Comment: estou usando o firefox quantum 58, aqui não vai.