# Jquery Dropdown, parar propagação com click direito

Tags: jquery

Estou utilizando o Jquery DropDown: https://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/

No issue do projeto, existe um código que impede que o menu se feche ao clicar como  botão esquerdo, gostaria que apenas não se fechasse com o click direito. No exemplo abaixo, quando se clica dentro de um link no dropdown, ele continua aberto, mas não com o click direito, suponhamos, para abrir o link em uma nova aba...

o código é esse que está fora da biblioteca.

```js
$("#jq-dropdown-1").on("click",function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#jq-dropdown-1').dropdown('show');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/jquery.dropdown.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/jquery.dropdown.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" data-jq-dropdown="#jq-dropdown-1">Dropdown</a>
<div id="jq-dropdown-1" class="jq-dropdown jq-dropdown-tip">
    <ul class="jq-dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Science</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Eletronics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pellentesque convallis enim.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Internet</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Em qual browser você tem esse problema?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo no firefox quantum 58.0.2

Comment: @LeandroAngelo no Chrome funciona perfeitamente, tanto o direito quanto o esquerdo. Nesse caso eu queria parar a propagação apenas com o clique direito em um link para abrir em uma nova aba. Tentei com contextmenu, mas não funciona no firefox.

Comment: O Firefox não gosta que você altere suas definições padrões e ao clicar com o botão direito o foco sai do seu dropdown e vai para o menu dele. Nessas últimas versões do browser só vi funcionar, com esse comportamento, o dropdown do bootstrap.

Comment: Vamos la John, ficou meio confuso sua pergunta, mas pelo que entendi, você quer que ao clicar com o botão direito em um link, redirecione para a página?

Comment: @Jorge o problema foi resolvido abaixo, por dvd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com recursos do plugin você não consegue fazer isso. Tem que criar um *event handler* que captura o clique direito e tratar das classes.

Para isso eu usei o `on contextmenu`, que vai impedir que o menu seja fechado no clique direito:

```js
$("#jq-dropdown-1").on("contextmenu", function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    
    var a = $("a[data-jq-dropdown='#jq-dropdown-1']");
    
    if(!$(a).hasClass("jq-dropdown-open")){
      $(this).toggle();
      $(a).toggleClass("jq-dropdown-open");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/jquery.dropdown.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/jquery.dropdown.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" data-jq-dropdown="#jq-dropdown-1">Dropdown</a>
<div id="jq-dropdown-1" class="jq-dropdown jq-dropdown-tip">
    <ul class="jq-dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Science</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Eletronics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pellentesque convallis enim.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Internet</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: genial como sempre. Obrigado.

Comment: Tenho uma pergunta interessante em PHP. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/277323/vari%C3%A1vel-pela-url-em-todos-os-links-da-p%C3%A1gina

Comment: Com PHP é complicado mudar os links da página. Não pode ser JavaScript?

Comment: Com JavaScript é possível, mas irá alterar todos os links da página. A não ser que vc queira alterar apenas uma coleção específica.

Comment: sim, pode ser com javascript, só preciso que o valor chamado da variável, ?layout=2 se aplique em todos os links da página.

Comment: mas ainda preciso que o valor chamado seja em php, já que também utilizo para chamar algum arquivo .php baseado na variável colocada na URL, só preciso então que esse valor se aplique a todos os links dentro dessa página, ou melhor, os links de posts, páginas, categorias, em fim, links da mesma URL.

Comment: Postei lá, mas vai sempre incluir `?layout=2` ao link (com a interrogação)... se algum link tiver outro parâmetro antes não vai funcionar. Ex.: localhost/wp/about/?outravariavel?layout=2

Comment: funciona bem,agora essa questão de outros parâmetros... meu objetivo era justamente utilizar vários parâmetros. exemplo: localhost/wp/about/?header=2&layout=3&footer=2

Comment: Pois é... espera aí que vou consertar isso