# Variável pela URL em todos os links da página

Tags: php, wordpress

Eu estou utilizando o seguinte código para passar variáveis através da URL, no wordpress.

```
if (isset($_GET['layout'])) {
    $layout = $_GET['layout'];
} else {
    $layout = '1';
}
```

Com `$layout` recupero o valor no código,onde utilizo para mudar o estilo do layout.

Ao chamar essa url tudo funciona muito bem.
**localhost/wp/?layout=2**

Nessa url existem vários links para outros posts, páginas, categorias, etc. Eu gostaria que ao chamar uma variável na URL, a mesma se aplicasse para todos os links dessa página.

**Por exemplo:**
eu começo chamando a variável `layout` na url
assim: **localhost/wp/?layout=2**

E nessa página terá um link para página "about": 
assim: **localhost/wp/about**

Queria que a variável `layout` fosse colocada automaticamente nela e em todos os outros links.

Desse jeito: **localhost/wp/about/?layout=2**, **localhost/wp/outra-pagina/?layout=2**, **localhost/wp/categoria/tecnologia/?layout=2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com PHP acho difícil fazer isso. Mas com JavaScript você consegue alterar todos os links.

O código abaixo verifica se a variável `layout` existe na URL. Se existe, adiciona ela e o seu valor a todos os links `<a>` da página:

```
var url_ = new URL(location.href),
    var_ = url_.searchParams.get("layout");
if(var_){
   var a_ = document.body.querySelectorAll("a");
   for(var x=0; x<a_.length; x++){
      a_[x].href += (a_[x].href.indexOf("?") == -1 ? "?" : "&")+"layout="+var_;
   }
}
```

Como o método `searchParams` não tem suporte no IE, segue uma forma alternativa:

```
var url_ = location.href,
    param = url_.indexOf("layout");
if(param != -1){
   var var_ = url_.substring(param+7,url_.length).match(/^(\d|\w){1,}/)[0],
       a_ = document.body.querySelectorAll("a");
   for(var x=0; x<a_.length; x++){
      a_[x].href += (a_[x].href.indexOf("?") == -1 ? "?" : "&")+"layout="+var_;
   }
}
```

### Edit

Para verificar múltiplas variáveis e aplicar aos links, pode inserir numa array os nomes que você quer manipular:

```
var url_ = location.href,
    param = url_.substring(url_.lastIndexOf("/"), url_.length),
    params = ['layout','teste']; // insira aqui os nomes das variáveis
for(var y=0; y<params.length; y++){
   if(param.indexOf(params[y]) != -1){
      var var_ = url_.substring(url_.indexOf(params[y])+params[y].length+1,url_.length).match(/^(\d|\w){1,}/)[0],
          a_ = document.body.querySelectorAll("a");
      for(var x=0; x<a_.length; x++){
         a_[x].href += (a_[x].href.indexOf("?") == -1 ? "?" : "&")+params[y]+"="+var_;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: funcionou, agora, a variável "layout" não é a única que pretendo utilizar: por exemplo esse código `var_ = url_.searchParams.get("layout");` para utilizar outra variável eu teria que duplica-lo.

Comment: Seria possível fazer algo como isso `url_.searchParams.get("layout", "outra_variavel", "outra");`

Comment: Creio que não. Estou fazendo outra resposta porque percebi que o `searchParams` não funciona no IE.

Comment: rsrs, imagino, blza então.

Comment: funciona, daria para utilizar múltiplas vars com o seu último código?

Comment: Adicionei na resposta uma solução.

Comment: Uma solução elegante e profissional. Só tenho mais uma coisinha, alias, sobre um ponto que você levantou.  (lembrando que os valores das variáveis devem ser números, segundo a regex `/^(\d){1,}/` ): eu já estava tentando aqui usar palavras... /?layout=boxed&skin=red é possível alterar isso? deixar tanto números quanto palavras?

Comment: Essa solução é demais. Funciona até mesmo no IE8.

Comment: `a_ = document.body.querySelectorAll("a");` Existe alguns links que eu não queira que peguem a variável. É porque existe alguns links externos da galeria, do footer, links sociais, etc. Links de posts, páginas, categorias são os que devem ter esse efeito. Pensei nisso: #menu ul li a, #list-posts a

Comment: `a_ = document.body.querySelectorAll(".my-post a, nav a, .menu-top a, .sidebar a");` funciona perfeitamente. Obrigado

Comment: Pode usar o seletor que pegue todos os links que vc quer.

Comment: fiz uma outra pergunta relacionada a essa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/277851/95735