# Passar variavéis para a url através de um Select Box

Tags: php, javascript

Com esse código em php, passamos variáveis para url manualmente.

```
if (isset($_GET['layout'])) {
    $layout = $_GET['layout'];
} else {
    $layout = '1';
}
```

Com esse outro, em javascript, de autoria do [@dvd](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277345/95735) aplicamos a variável passada na URL em todos os links da página.

```
var url_ = location.href,
    param = url_.substring(url_.lastIndexOf("/"), url_.length),
    params = ['layout','teste']; // insira aqui os nomes das variáveis
for(var y=0; y<params.length; y++){
   if(param.indexOf(params[y]) != -1){
      var var_ = url_.substring(url_.indexOf(params[y])+params[y].length+1,url_.length).match(/^(\d|\w){1,}/)[0],
          a_ = document.body.querySelectorAll("a");
      for(var x=0; x<a_.length; x++){
         a_[x].href += (a_[x].href.indexOf("?") == -1 ? "?" : "&")+params[y]+"="+var_;
      }
   }
}
```

Tudo isso funciona muito. O que eu gostaria agora é. Passar as variáveis para URL, através de um select box.

```
<select id="layout" name="layout">
    <option value="/?layout=1" selected="selected">Layout 1</option>
    <option value="/?layout=2">Layout 2</option>
    <option value="/?layout=3">Layout 3</option>
    <option value="/?layout=4">Layout 4</option>
</select>
```

Lembrando que pode ter mais de um select. Um para **layout**, outro para **sidebar**, e que a seleção de um, deve se manter quando outro for selecionado e a página for atualizada.

Comment: Você quer fazer a mesma coisa, mudar os links da página, só que agora usando selects?

Comment: @dvd exatamente.

Comment: @dvd, sim, isso mesmo.

Comment: Mas aí ficou confuso pra mim. Qual a relação da variável na URL da página com os selects box? Por exemplo, digamos que a URL da página seja: site.com.br/?layout=2.... qual a relação com o select box?

Comment: @dvd eu chamo a variável, digitando ela no input do browser certo? `?layout=2` `?layout=3` etc... Eu quero chama-las através do select, e não ter que digita-las no input do navegador.

Comment: @dvd acredito que deverá ter um refresh na página quando o select for selecionado certo? e não tem problema, acho que a sua solução em javascript atual deverá se aplicar automaticamente, já que a página se atualizou e ela pegará a url.

Comment: Eu entendi assim: verifica-se se na URL tem uma das variaveis, seleciona automaticamente no respectivo select e insere nos links da página... é isso?

Comment: @dvd é exatamente isso.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73488/discussion-between-dvd-and-john-quimera).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode colocar nos `values` apenas o valor da variável que o código irá capturar normalmente. Também adicionei um `option` vazio que será o padrão caso não haja na URL a respectiva variável:

```
<select id="layout" name="layout">
    <option value="">Layout</option>
    <option value="1">Layout 1</option>
    <option value="2">Layout 2</option>
    <option value="3">Layout 3</option>
    <option value="4">Layout 4</option>
</select>

<select id="sidebar" name="sidebar">
    <option value="">sidebar</option>
    <option value="1">sidebar 1</option>
    <option value="2">sidebar 2</option>
    <option value="3">sidebar 3</option>
    <option value="4">sidebar 4</option>
</select>
```

E o código que irá alterar as variáveis e os links e fazer o *refresh* na página quando algum select for alterado:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

   var url_ = location.href,
       param = url_.substring(url_.lastIndexOf("/"), url_.length),
       params = ['layout','sidebar']; // insira aqui os nomes das variáveis
   for(var y=0; y<params.length; y++){
      if(param.indexOf(params[y]) != -1){

         var var_ = url_.substring(url_.indexOf(params[y])+params[y].length+1,url_.length).match(/^(\d|\w){1,}/)[0],
             a_ = document.body.querySelectorAll("a");

         document.body.querySelector("#"+params[y]).value = var_;

         for(var x=0; x<a_.length; x++){
            a_[x].href += (a_[x].href.indexOf("?") == -1 ? "?" : "&")+params[y]+"="+var_;
         }
      }
   }

   var sels = document.querySelectorAll("select");

   for(var x=0; x<sels.length; x++){
      sels[x].addEventListener("change", function(){

         var sId = this.id,
             sVa = this.value;

         if(sVa && url_.indexOf(sId) == -1){

            location.href = url_+(url_.indexOf("?") == -1 ? "?" : "&")+sId+"="+sVa;

         }else if(sVa && url_.indexOf(sId+"="+sVa) == -1){

            var var_ = url_.substring(url_.indexOf(sId)+sId.length+1,url_.length).match(/^(\d|\w){1,}/)[0];

            location.href = url_.replace(sId+"="+var_, sId+"="+sVa);

         }

      });
   }

});
```

Comment: Como sempre. Solução extraordinária. Imagino que também posso utilizar radio em vez de select, alterando em `var sels = document.querySelectorAll("radio");`

Comment: compreendo, era só por curiosidade, pensei em algo, talvez eu use um select e um radio. Por hoje isso está bom. Qualquer coisa eu dou um toque. Obrigadão! ;)

Comment: ei, não seria interessante um botão para resetar todas as variáveis?

Comment: Mais uma mãozinha. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/280250/95735

Comment: opa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/280501/95735

Comment: A questão de segurança não é importante. Isso é para demonstração. Então não tem problema. É porque terá várias variáveis, então ficará muito grande o endereço.

Comment: Ao meu ver, isso parece resolvido com sua própria solução para o select. Quando seleciono uma variável no select, ela fica marcada no próprio select. Estando a variável na URL, marcada no select é o suficiente.

Comment: Rapaz, deve ser isso mesmo, agora que você falou, acho que é justamente isso que eu queria. Algo semelhantes aos encurtadores de url, biy.ly, etc.

Comment: A base para o que eu estou querendo é o seu próprio código nessa questão. Tudo está funcionando perfeitamente bem. Só queria mascarar as variáveis que aparecem na URL.

Comment: Rapaz, seria um máximo, eu gostaria muito de ver isso em funcionamento. Nesse caso as vars seriam passadas para a URL, mas não apareceriam na URL?

Comment: Isso. Mas teria que fazer um refresh

Comment: é uma boa ideia, mas nesse caso isso só funcionaria no Browser do user atual certo?, não podendo assim enviar o link para outra pessoa.

Comment: Não porque para isso teria que envolver banco de dados ou outro recurso do lado do servidor

Comment: Compreendo. Então nesse caso a mascara na URL seria mais interessante, apesar de eu estar interessado na sua sugestão. Atualmente está assim: **site.io/?cor=red&fundo=img&sidebar=left**
Por exemplo, as vars somando com o valor e os sinais tem 30 caracteres. Eu pensei que talvez não fosse necessário gerar automaticamente um code para cada var, poderia ser definido manualmente. por exemplo: **?cor=red** ficaria assim: **cr** tipo, pegar a primeira letra da var e a primeira do valor.

Comment: Assim fica muito complicado e a URL continuaria longa (talvez nem tanto), mas pra saber o que é **cr** seria complicadíssimo

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74028/discussion-between-dvd-and-john-quimera).