# Remover Class de uma div parent baseado na classe do elemento filho

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou utilizando o LazySizes para carregar imagens progressivamente.
https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes

Esse é o estilo do meu projeto

`<div class="image-wrap">
    <img class="lazyload" src="">
</div>`

Quando as imagens estão carregando, a tag IMG ganha uma nova classe **lazyloading** e ao finalizar o carregamento, ela é substituída pela classe **lazyloaded**

O que eu gostaria de fazer é, colocar ou remover uma classe na **DIV.image-wrap**, baseado na classe **.lazyloading** do elemento IMG.

```html
<script src="https://afarkas.github.io/lazysizes/lazysizes.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="image-wrap">
  <a href="#">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150">
   </a>
</div>
<div class="image-wrap">
  <a href="#">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/">
   </a>
</div>
<div class="image-wrap">
  <a href="#">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/nature/">
   </a>
</div>
<div class="image-wrap">
  <a href="#">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/cats/">
   </a>
</div>
<div class="image-wrap">
  <a href="#">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/business/">
   </a>
</div>
<div class="image-wrap">
  <a href="#">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/city/">
   </a>
</div>
<div class="image-wrap">
  <a href="#">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/people/">
   </a>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: poderia colocar o codigo que está utilizando do lazysizes?

Comment: vc deverá colocar provavelmente no callback do carregamento da imagem algo como `$(this).parents("div.image-wrap").removeClass("image-wrap");` mas para dar a resposta correta é preciso inserir isso no seu código

Comment: @KarlZillner eu apenas chamo a classe padrão "lazyload" da lib LazySizes.min.js e tudo funciona como pretendido.

Comment: Vou colocar um exemplo aqui no stack.

Comment: @KarlZillner postei o código.

Comment: Como assim "baseado na classe .lazyloading"?

Comment: @dvd Com o lazysizes as imagens vão carregando uma por uma. A classe padrão no elemento IMG é **lazyload** e quando uma imagem está carregando a classe **lazyloading** entra em ação ao lado dela, e quando finaliza o carregamento dessa imagem, a classe lazyloading é substituida pela classe **lazyloaded** o que eu quero agora é usar adicionar/remover uma classe da div.parent baseado nas classes que entram em atividade no IMG.

Comment: @dvd Quando a classe **lazyloading** estiver em atividade no elemento IMG, quero uma outra classe entre em atividade na DIV da qual o elemento IMG está dentro, e quando a classe lazyloading não estiver mais, que o mesmo ocorra com a class da div parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode colocar a primeira classe em todos os elementos com `.image-wrap` no carregamento da página, e usar `on load` para detectar quando a imagem é carregada. Adicionei também `on error` para aplicar o mesmo efeito caso o carregamento da imagem falhe (o `on error` é opcional, pode retirar se desejar).

No exemplo abaixo eu coloquei a primeira classe com fundo vermelho, e a segunda com fundo azul:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".image-wrap").addClass("classe1");

   const els = $(".image-wrap").find("img");
   
   els.each(function(){
      $(this).on("load error", function(){
         $(this)
         .closest(".image-wrap")
         .addClass("classe2")
         .removeClass("classe1");
      });
   });
});
```

```css
/*linhas só para exemplo*/

.classe1{
   background: red;
}

.classe2{
   background: blue;
}

.image-wrap{
   padding: 15px;
   margin: 5px;
   position:relative;
}
.classe1:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: -20px 0 0 -20px;
    content: "";
    background: #f7f7f7 url(//afarkas.github.io/lazysizes/assets/imgs/loader.gif) no-repeat center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://afarkas.github.io/lazysizes/lazysizes.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="image-wrap">
  <a href="#">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150">
   </a>
</div>
<div class="image-wrap">
  <a href="#">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/">
   </a>
</div>
<div class="image-wrap">
  <a href="#">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/nature/">
   </a>
</div>
<div class="image-wrap">
  <a href="#">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/cats/">
   </a>
</div>
<div class="image-wrap">
  <a href="#">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/business/">
   </a>
</div>
<div class="image-wrap">
  <a href="#">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/city/">
   </a>
</div>
<div class="image-wrap">
  <a href="#">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/people/">
   </a>
</div>

</div>
```

### Edit

Pode usar também os eventos do plugin, `lazybeforeunveil` e `lazyloaded`, só que eles não detectam quando o carregamento da imagem falha:

```js
$(document).on('lazybeforeunveil lazyloaded', function(e){

  if(e.type == 'lazyloaded'){
    var addClass = 'classe2',
    removeClass = 'classe1';
  }else{
    var addClass = 'classe1',
    removeClass = 'classe2';
  }
  
  $(e.target)
  .closest('.image-wrap')
  .addClass(addClass)
  .removeClass(removeClass);
});
```

```css
/*linhas só para exemplo*/

.classe1{
   background: red;
}

.classe2{
   background: blue;
}

.image-wrap{
   padding: 15px;
   margin: 5px;
   position:relative;
}
.classe1:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: -20px 0 0 -20px;
    content: "";
    background: #f7f7f7 url(//afarkas.github.io/lazysizes/assets/imgs/loader.gif) no-repeat center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://afarkas.github.io/lazysizes/lazysizes.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="image-wrap">
  <a href="#">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150">
   </a>
</div>
<div class="image-wrap">
  <a href="#">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/">
   </a>
</div>
<div class="image-wrap">
  <a href="#">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/nature/">
   </a>
</div>
<div class="image-wrap">
  <a href="#">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/cats/">
   </a>
</div>
<div class="image-wrap">
  <a href="#">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/business/">
   </a>
</div>
<div class="image-wrap">
  <a href="#">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/city/">
   </a>
</div>
<div class="image-wrap">
  <a href="#">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/people/">
   </a>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: ,Essa solução funciona muito bem até certo ponto. Apenas nos items visíveis, com scroll ela não funciona. Esse lazysizes carrega imagens quando elas ficam visíveis.

Comment: Sim, de fato, algumas imagens realmente carregam antes de ficar visivel, eu executei agora o seu código, e a ultima imagem carrega, mas está vermelha.

Comment: testei, está do mesmo jeito, eu consegui resolver mais ou menos com isso `$(window).on("load resize scroll",function(e){` funciona como esperado. Mas existe um atraso, o efeito continua por um tempo mesmo com a imagem carregada.

Comment: O correto é usar onload. Alterei a resposta.

Comment: Ontem também tinha postado essa pergunta no issue dessa lib no github, vi aqui agora que o autor dela me respondeu, olha a resposta dele:  https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/issues/474

Comment: Funciona também, ele tá usando os eventos do plugin. Eu havia visto isso na documentação do plugin mas achei meio confuso as explicações e resolvi fazer do meu jeito. Mas funciona também.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazer do seguinte modo usando **JQuery**:

```
$('.lazyload').parent().removeClass('image-wrap')
```

Comment: safadenho voce kkk

Comment: Testei sua solução, mas não funcionou como esperava, adicionei um exemplo na questão.