# Encriptar variáveis na URL

Tags: javascript

Com solução do @dvd, passamos variáveis para a URL através de um select: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277883/95735

São várias que ficam assim quando são passadas: **example.com/?fundo=img&cor=red**

O que eu gostaria de fazer agora é: encriptar a variável e seu valor na URL.

Mais ou menos asssim: **example.com/?d5t9a15d2a54ds54d5**

Comment: Pra que finalidade fazer isso ?

Comment: @MarceloRafael para deixar curta a URL com as variáveis passadas.

Comment: Você pode converter os parâmetros para `base64` com o `btoa`, mas já adianto que não vai diminuir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode alterar a URL no navegador com `history.pushState`. Para gerar um número variável, você pode pegar a hora do sistema com `new Date().getTime()` e colocar na URL preservando as variáveis passadas.

A URL no navegador ficaria algo como:

```
example.com/?1520231465457
```

O código ficaria assim:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

   var url_short = new Date().getTime(),
       url_ = location.href,
       param = url_.substring(url_.lastIndexOf("/")+1, url_.length),
       params = ['layout','sidebar']; // insira aqui os nomes das variáveis

   history.pushState(null, '', '?'+url_short);

   for(var y=0; y<params.length; y++){
      if(param.indexOf(params[y]) != -1){

         var var_ = url_.substring(url_.indexOf(params[y])+params[y].length+1,url_.length).match(/^(\d|\w){1,}/)[0],
             a_ = document.body.querySelectorAll("a");

         document.body.querySelector("#"+params[y]).value = var_;

         for(var x=0; x<a_.length; x++){
            a_[x].href += (a_[x].href.indexOf("?") == -1 ? "?" : "&")+params[y]+"="+var_;
         }
      }
   }

   var sels = document.querySelectorAll("select");

   for(var x=0; x<sels.length; x++){
      sels[x].addEventListener("change", function(){

         var sId = this.id,
             sVa = this.value;

         if(sVa && url_.indexOf(sId) == -1){

            location.href = url_+(url_.indexOf("?") == -1 ? "?" : "&")+sId+"="+sVa;

         }else if(sVa && url_.indexOf(sId+"="+sVa) == -1){

            var var_ = url_.substring(url_.indexOf(sId)+sId.length+1,url_.length).match(/^(\d|\w){1,}/)[0];

            location.href = url_.replace(sId+"="+var_, sId+"="+sVa);

         }

      });
   }

});
```

**[Página de teste.](http://dvdteste.hospedagemdesites.ws)**

Comment: apliquei aqui, e está funcionando como esperado, imagino que o pequeno atraso que existe no input do browser ao mascarar a as vars passadas seja algo inevitável nesse caso.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada melhor nesse atraso e ver se pode melhorar.

Comment: e um botão reset seria possível?

Comment: como assim um botão?

Comment: um botão para resetar todas as variáveis.

Comment: Basta dar um refresh na página sem as variáveis.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74067/discussion-between-john-quimera-and-dvd).

Comment: essas questões só você consegue resolver. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/281563/95735

Comment: Vc quer o valor em em pixels ou %? Digamos, imagem de 300x200, vai dar uma proporção de 1,5... vc quer que converta esse 1,5 em q?

Comment: É em %, é tudo com base nisso aqui: https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/full/OMGOyE/ 300x200 é igual a 66.67%; que é posto no padding-bottom

Answer (score 1):

Use o pacote [Crypto-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js)

Basta descomentar a primeira `var search` para pegar os paramêtros

```js
//var search = window.location.search;
var search = '?name=fulaninho&pass=12312313&address=rua+dos+taubatucos+numero+22';
var pass   = '9090';

var enc = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(search, pass).toString();
var dec = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(enc, pass).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

console.log(search);
console.log(enc);
console.log(dec);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Você pediu para deixar a URL curta, pra mim isso não tem como. Mas está aí, de uma certa forma adiciona um pouco de segurança para a sua aplicação

Comment: estou tentando aplicar sua solução a esse código https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277883/95735